# Setting Boundaries around city in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

I'm looking for a way to set boundaries around a specific city/town within the Google maps API V3 using JavaScript

Is this type of thing even supported within the API?

Basically i don't want my users to be able to pan across the map further then the city, including country area's not just city limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well the boundry that you want to provide to the city/ town can be done. you just need to draw the polylines or polygons specifying the co ordinates of the boundries of the city.
 visit  [demos and documentation for overlays in Gmap V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays)

try the following code to restrict user to pan across the region.

```
 // Bounds for North America
   var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(28.70, -127.50), 
     new google.maps.LatLng(48.85, -55.90)
   );

   // Listen for the dragend event
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
     if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

     // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

     var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

     if (x < minX) x = minX;
     if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
     if (y < minY) y = minY;
     if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
   });
```

this will restrict user to pan across region of north america

Comment: they have to be able to pan accross the map, otherwise i lose the whole user interactivity that im looking for.

Comment: u want to limit user to be able to pan only inside the circle right!!

Comment: amazing, it looks great, like i told the other guy, once i get to work tomorrow i will try it out. And let you know if its working correctly, im sure it will with the code you have provided with your edit.

Would i be able to not make a circle but yet pick and choose from coord to coord?

Comment: Do i declare all of this under the initialize function? Or outside of that function?

Comment: I got my answer to the comment above, yes i do place it within the Initialize fuction, guess i should of read through the whole link you posted before asking stupid questions. That link really helps me alot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the points for boundries of the city, then you can create a polyline. For example, one idea could be similar to this:

```
limitCoord = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.49956716,-7.019005501),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.49947126,-7.029286373),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.50904062,-7.049299123),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.50722622,-7.069103626),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.50452387,-7.000150672),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.49348015,-6.983058917),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.49843269,-6.971666546),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.51765791,-6.956909023),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.52010069,-6.927429186),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.50992238,-6.914231493),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.50096695,-6.879679821),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.48775868,-6.857775832),
    new google.maps.LatLng(43.23907504,-3.293216584)], "#000000", 5);

var boundries = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: limitCoord,
    strokeColor: "#000000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
});
```

Comment: Looks great, will try implementing it when i get to work tomorrow and will let you know the final results.

Will this actually stop them from moving past those coords? Or will it only draw a line of the strokeColor?

Comment: Will only draw a line of the stroke color, hope this helps you, at least could help you to improve your idea

Comment: It does indeed, the bounderies varibale you created will help with the design alot, just not the functionallity. Either way, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `map.fitBounds()` or `map.setCenter()` to center the city/country/region on the map.
2. Use `draggable: false` option to disable panning.